# How do I define another default ssh identity?

Tags: default, ssh

id_rsa is, normally a default identity. However, 
I've created a new key and I would like to add that key as a default identify instead.

How can we do that?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your ~/.ssh/config file (create it if it doesn't already exist), you can specify which key to use with the IdentityFile directive:

```
IdentityFile ~/path/to/your/key
```

You can use this directive inside a "Host" section if you only want to use that key for a particular host.  For example:

```
Host *.example.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity-example.com
```

If you run "ssh -v hostname", the debug information should confirm that it is using the key you specified.

Comment: About your last example, when you have identity-example you are refering to the key name or, some sort of syntax using specificly the -myhost, like: "mykeyname-myhost.com" ?

Comment: That's just the file name.  So to use that configuration, I'd need to have ~/.ssh/identity-example.com and ~/.ssh/identity-example.com.pub files.  The file names don't really matter.